# How to make the AJAX contact form actually send mail?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, contact-form

I have a contact form with all the necessary basic functions the form needed. I excluded `action=""` as it's not needed when using AJAX. When I input all the required fields in the contact form, it simply says message was sent, but actually did not receive anything. I checked the browser's debugger,it received the information of the input fields perfectly, but it will only go up to `success: function(msg) {` before backing out of the ajax function and returning false. Other times, it will say your message was sent successfully, but didn't actually send the email. What is it am I doing wrong or am missing?

My website is here for reference: http://www.jaimepenzellna.com

**index.html:** (contact form)

```
<form method="post" id="contactForm" role="form">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
          <div class="form-group wow bounceInUp">
            <label for="contactName">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" size="35" class="form-control" name="contactName" id="contactName" title="Please enter your name (at least 2 characters)">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group wow bounceInUp">
            <label for="contactEmail">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" size="35" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" title="Please enter a valid email address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group wow bounceInUp">
            <label for="contactSubject">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" size="35" class="form-control" name="contactSubject" id="contactSubject">
          </div>
           <div class="form-group wow bounceInUp">
            <label for="contactMessage">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <textarea name="contactMessage" class="form-control" id="contactMessage" cols="50" rows="15" title="Please enter your message (at least 10 characters)"></textarea>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group wow bounceInUp">
               <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
               <span id="image-loader">
                <img alt="" src="images/loader.gif">
               </span>
               <!-- contact-warning -->
               <div id="message-warning">Error!</div>
               <!-- contact-success -->
               <div id="message-success">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br/>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

(script at the bottom of the body tag)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('form#contactForm button#submit').click(function() {

      $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

      var contactName = $('#contactForm #contactName').val();
      var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
      var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
      var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

      var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
               '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

      $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(msg) {

            // Message was sent
            if (msg == 'OK') {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').hide();
               $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
               $('#message-success').fadeIn();
            }
            // There was an error
            else {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').html(msg);
               $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
            }

          }

      });
      return false;
   });


});
```

**sendMail.php:**

```
<?php

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'jnp5028@rit.edu';


if($_POST) {

   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
   $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
   $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

   // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
   // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


   // Set Message
   $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
   $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
   $message .= "Message: <br />";
   $message .= $contact_message;
   $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

   // Set From: header
   $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

   // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


   if (!$error) {

      ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
      $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
      else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

    } # end if - no validation error

    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

        echo $response;

    } # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
```

Comment: Are there any PHP errors that you can find (in your PHP error_log)? I'd also recommend to not have your initial if-statement to be `if($_POST) {` but rather `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {`, as I'm not entirely sure if $_POST exists when no POST request is made.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested about post. Everything seems to be working fine, no errors in php. I checked using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. I checked by validating the form inputs and it won't send until everything is put in correctly. When that's done, it'll display that the message was sent successfully, but it didn't actually send or receive the email to my inbox. How I do make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know to debug a contact form is as follows:

Add the below to the top of the php file:

```
error_reporting(-1);` 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Then create an html page with just the bare bones of your contact form like the below. note the addition of `action="sendEmail.php"` on the form and set the path as appropriate:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="contactForm" role="form" action="sendEmail.php">
 Name: <input type="text" size="35" class="form-control" name="contactName" id="contactName" title="Please enter your name (at least 2 characters)"><br>
 Email: <input type="email" size="35" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" title="Please enter a valid email address"><br>
 Subject: <input type="text" size="35" class="form-control" name="contactSubject" id="contactSubject"><br>
 Body: <textarea name="contactMessage" class="form-control" id="contactMessage" cols="50" rows="15" title="Please enter your message (at least 10 characters)"></textarea><br>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Upload the files to a server then use the form to post directly to the php page. This will show you any errors that are being generated in your php file right oon the screen.

Doing this we see that we get the error:

`Notice: Undefined variable: message in /home/content/08/10125908/html/sendEmail.php on line 39`

This is telling us that on line 39, we try to use a variable called "message" but there is no such variable available.

This is because of this line `$message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";`, specifically this part `$message .=`which is saying "take the string variable `$message` and append the following to it" but `$message` is not defined, thus the error.

We can fix this by declaring `$message`as an empty string before we use it like `$message ='';`

Fixing that and trying it again, we get a new error:

`Notice: Undefined variable: error in /home/content/08/10125908/html/sendEmail.php on line 56`

This is telling us that on line 56, we try to use a variable called "error" but there is no such variable available.

This is because we only declare `$error` in the if statement if there is an error, if there is no error, it never gets set and is therefore undefined when we try to use it.

We can fix this by either declaring `error` up with the name and subject stuff like `$error = array()` or, by using `if (isset($error))` to check if the variable has been declared (I prefer the latter but note that this reverses the if clause and the failure code will need to be first then the success code, you could do `if (!isset($error))` but then the logic gets hard to follow)

Fix those two errors and you're all set! [Working example](http://dodsoftware.com/rawform.html)

**So, the fixed php file would look like:**

```
    <?php

// the next two lines will turn on error reporting for the page
// uncomment them to see warnings
// error_reporting(-1); 
// ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
// these are really only useful if you actually go to the page 
// you wont see the warnings if you call the page with ajax


// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'jnp5028@rit.edu';


if($_POST) {

   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
   $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
   $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));
   // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
   // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


   // Set Message
   $message =''; // you need to define  `$message` as an empty string, otherwise when the `$message .=` on the next line tries to use it, it is undefined
   $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
   $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
   $message .= "Message: <br />";
   $message .= $contact_message;
   $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

   // Set From: header
   $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

   // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


   if (isset($error)) {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

        echo $response;


    } # end if - there was a validation error
    else {


      ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
      $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
      else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

    } # end if - no validation error

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to thoroughly test the contact form. The working example works perfectly, but for some reason my site doesn't. I think maybe it has to do with server configurations to allow emails through?

Comment: That is very likely, if I'm not mistaken, your site is on a school server? If so mail may be disabled by default or you may have to configure appache to send email. If you cant run email form your server that way, you could use phpmailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead, here is a tutorial http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#1 wouldn't be too difficult to rewrite it with phpmailer if you have to.

Comment: Just read your email, if your test form works, there is a problem elsewhere, checking it again now

Comment: Actually I just found out, it didn't actually send the message.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah you might have seen the one I sent to you earlier when I was testing it from my site and forgot to change the address : )